# Dependency injection: Accessing services in code behind file of another project

Tags: c#, mvvm, dependency-injection, winui-3

I used [Template Studio for WinUI](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TemplateStudio.TemplateStudioForWinUICs) to create a new application. I want to stick to the dependency injection approach which is created from the template.

The template provide the following code for `App.xaml.cs`:

```
public partial class App : Application {
    
    private static readonly IHost _host = Host
        .CreateDefaultBuilder()       
        .ConfigureServices((context, services) => {
            // Services
// ...
            services.AddTransient<IFileOpenPickerService, FileOpenPickerService>();

            // Core Services
             services.AddSingleton<IFileService, FileService>();

            // Views and ViewModels
            services.AddTransient<SolutionListDetailsViewModel>();
            services.AddTransient<SolutionListDetailsPage>();
            services.AddTransient<MainViewModel>();
            services.AddTransient<MainPage>();

            // Configuration
        })
        .Build();

    public static T? GetService<T>()
        where T : class {
        return _host.Services.GetService(typeof(T)) as T;
    }
// ...
}
```

For a control in the main project the viewmodel creation looks like this in the template:

```
public sealed partial class SolutionListDetailsPage : Page {
    public SolutionListDetailsViewModel ViewModel {
        get;
    }

    public SolutionListDetailsPage() {
        ViewModel = App.GetService<SolutionListDetailsViewModel>();
        InitializeComponent();
    }
//...
}
```

However, I want to implement a control in a second project, which is referenced and used by the main project, and here the line

```
ViewModel = App.GetService<MyOwnViewModelWhichIRegisteredAsAService>();
```

does not work anymore, because I do not have access to `App.GetService()` in the second project. Furthermore, I cannot let the service provider provide the control and pass the view model in its constructor, since it is created within XAML code. How do I access the service provider to get the view model?

One solution is to create the view model somewhere else and bind it to the `DataContext`-property. But then I have a different viewmodel-creation-mechanism for the new control than for the old one, which I would like to avoid. (And I am not sure if it works with WinUI's `x:Bind`.)

Comment: Looks complicated. I'd implement the ViewModel in the main project.

Comment: Sure, that would work. But it does not scale. Should I implement all views/viewModels in the main project just because App.GetService can't be accessed elsewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to access to the registerd services from other projects, you can use the [Ioc class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.toolkit.mvvm.dependencyinjection.ioc?view=win-comm-toolkit-dotnet-7.0) from the CommunityTookit.

```cs
var service = Ioc.Default.GetRequiredServices<ISecondProjectClass>();
```

Also, regarding to several projects use cases, you can also register your services from your second project by creating an extension method:

```cs
namespace SecondProject;
public static class SecondProjectHostBuilderExtensions
{
    public static IHostBuilder AddSecondProjectServices(this IHostBuilder hostBuilder)
        => hostBuilder.ConfigureServices((context, services) =>
        {
            _ = services
                .AddSingleton<ISecondProjectClass, SecondProjectClass>();
        });
}
```

Call it at App.xaml.cs:

```cs
public partial class App : Application
{
    private readonly IHost _host;

    public App()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        _host = CreateHost();
        Ioc.Default.ConfigureServices(_host.Services);
    }

    private static IHost CreateHost()
    {
        return Host
            .CreateDefaultBuilder()
            .AddSecondProjectServices()
            .Build();
    }
```

Then if you want to get these services at your second project:

```cs
namespace SecondProject;
public class SomeClassAtSecondProject
{
    public SomeClassAtSecondProject()
    {
        var secondProjectClass = Ioc.Default.GetRequiredService<ISecondProjectClass>();
    }
}
```

Comment: The extension approach is good style, but besides my point. The solution you implicitly propose is to use Ioc.Default from the MS community toolkit. It is a static global variable, which can be accessed from all projects, which solve the original problem. Would you mind to make this more explicit in you answer? Additionally, I wonder if calling Ioc.Default.ConfigureServices(_host.Services) is equivalent to call IHostBuilder.ConfigureServices.

Comment: The ``Ioc`` class is just a helper to access the ``ServiceProvider``. So even when you use the extension method above, all your services will be the same provider.

Answer (score 0):

My current solution is to add a static class in the second project like this:

```
public static class ServiceProviderWorkaround {
    private static Func<Type, object?>? getService;
    public static void Init(Func<Type, object?> getter) {
        if (getService != null)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Provider already initialized");
        getService = getter;
    }

    internal static T? GetService<T>() where T : class 
        => getService == null 
        ? throw new InvalidOperationException("Provider not initialized") 
        : getService(typeof(T)) as T;

    internal static T GetRequiredService<T>() where T : class
        => getService == null 
        ? throw new InvalidOperationException("Provider not initialized") 
        : (T)getService(typeof(T))!;
}
```

It is initialized in the constructor of the `Application`-class:

```
public App() {
        InitializeComponent();
        UnhandledException += App_UnhandledException;
        ServiceProviderWorkaround.Init(_ => _host.Services.GetService(_));
    }
```

and can be used like this:

```
var service = ServiceProviderWorkaround.GetService<MyOwnViewModelWhichIRegisteredAsAService>();
```

Any better solution is still welcome.